# How to connect an iOS Swift application to a hardware device using socket programming?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, tcp, socket.io

I want to connect my Swift application to a networking hardware device using socket programming. The server side programming is already done in the hardware device using C language. How can I connect and communicate with the device using socket programming ? Which library should I choose ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do your own socket networking, the NSStream and CFStream APIs can be used from Swift to connect/read/write from/to raw network sockets.

Here are some useful Swift 3 snippets for using a socket via NSStream:

```
var readStream:  Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
var inputStream   : InputStream?    =  nil
var outputStream  : OutputStream?   =  nil

let host : CFString = NSString(string: someHostIPString)
let port : UInt32   = UInt32(somePortNumber)

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       host,
                                       port,
                                       &readStream,
                                       &writeStream)

inputStream  = readStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
outputStream = writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue()

// the enclosing class should be a StreamDelegate
//   to handle stream open, events, or errors, etc.
inputStream!.delegate   = self
outputStream!.delegate  = self

inputStream.open()
outputStream.open()

// the NSStream delegate callback(s)
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    var n = 0
    switch (eventCode) {
    ...
    case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
    n = self.outputStream.write(someWriteBuffer, maxLength: dataLength) 
    ...
    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
    n = self.inputStream.read(someReadBuffer, maxLength: bufferLength)
    ...
    // etc.
    }
}

// etc.
```

You may want to run the above code in its own thread with its own runloop.

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite understand your answer as I am a newbie. I was looking for some library that can be used to communicate with the device using socket programming.

Comment: The above code snippets show how to open, read from and write to a socket (via delegation callbacks in Swift).  Is there some other form of socket communication you need?